# Simple code to wake up my device

Tags: java, android

Hello guys and developers and thanks to be here.

I'm making an app for just personal use to wake up the screen of my device when volume buttons are pressed. I actually know how to intercepted the volume button pressed but I don't know how to make the screen to be on. All methods I saw here on the forum are deprecated. So what I'm asking is just a simple procedure with the code to turn screen on that will be called after any volume button has been pressed. Or maybe an explanation of how I can do it on my own.

Thanks

Comment: do you want  device wake up or app wake up..?

Answer (score 0):

Add permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

the use KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
        wakeUpScreen();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Screen wake Up

```
private void wakeUpScreen() {
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
}
```